# returning from a function immediately after calling another function

Tags: python, coding-style, return-value

Function `calculate_attribute` does not return a value; it only works through side effects.

Often within that function I have to write these few lines:

```
print('some message')
set_attribute(value)
return
```

So I decided to put this into a different function:

```
def report_and_set(value, message):
  print(message)
  set_attribute(value)
```

Is it ok to now do the following:

```
   def calculate_attribute(params):
     #...
     if something:
       return report_and_set(value, message)
     #...
     if another_condition:
       return report_and_set(value, message)
     #...
```

It feels kinda weird to write this since `report_and_set` has no return value. But if I don't, I'd have to repeatedly type `return` after every call to `report_and_set`.

Comment: Technically speaking, it does have a return value. If there's no return statement, functions return None by default. How about using elif statements? Then you could just call report_and_set() without worrying about using return to exit the function.

Comment: It may be *refactor time*, but it's hard to say without knowing what you're function is really about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many programmers, myself included, [prefer a single `return` per function](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/118703/5380).

Occasionally, I may insert a `return` in the first few lines of a function to bail if some sanity check fails.

I wouldn't in this case.

In this case, I would simply do...

```
   def calculate_attribute(params):
     #...
     if something:
       report_and_set(value, message)
     #...
     elif another_condition:
       report_and_set(value, message)
     #...
```

But also consider the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/curlys-law-do-one-thing.html) (it applies equally to functions and classes). If your function is long and contains lots of conditional function invocations,
it's probably time to [refactor](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/)!

Comment: I think single entry single exit is different from "one return only," which seems quite strict, and onerous at times. The [second answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/118793) to the question you linked to suggests that "one return only" is based on a misunderstanding of SESE. Still, I agree that in general, counting `return` statements is one rough heuristic for measuring function complexity; more returns = more [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).

Comment: @senderle: +1 a very interesting insight and link.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have to type `return` every time either way. I'm not sure what you gain (or lose) by doing it the way you suggest, especially since

```
return
```

is effectively the same as

```
return None
```

But I wonder why you have these empty return statements in the function at all. Is it necessary? There might be a more elegant or easier-to-read way to handle the flow of control in this function. A random `return` in the middle of a function can be easy to miss.

More abstractly speaking, counting return statements is a good rough heuristic for measuring function complexity; most of the time, more returns implies more [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity). There's even a school of thought that insists on using `return` only once in any given function, based on the oft-cited principle of "single entry, single exit." In fact, I think "single entry, single exit" is different from "one return only," which to me seems quite strict, and onerous at times. (For more, see [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/118793), which suggests that "one return only" is based on a misunderstanding of SESE). But the general principle that fewer `return` statements is better still seems like a good one to me.

Comment: Oops, yeah, I should have clarified that I only save a new line; I still need to type `return` of course. Also can you move your comment to your answer, since it's very useful?

Comment: @max, glad you found it useful! I incorporated it into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is okay to do this.

No, there's nothing wrong.

Carry on.